# JSF -- new timestamp overrides the old record

Tags: java, timestamp

I have generated a web CRUD application inside netbenas ide.

The following are snipplets of an entity class:

```
@Column(name = "TESTTIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)    
private Date testtimestamp;  

public Date getTesttimestamp() {    
   long ts = new Date().getTime() + TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney").getOffset(new Date().getTime());
   testtimestamp = new Date(ts);
   return testtimestamp;
}

public void setTesttimestamp(Date testtimestamp) {                        
   this.testtimestamp = testtimestamp;
}
```

When I create a record from web page it has correct timestamp value.
But if I create another record using the same page both timestamp (old and new) set to the same new value.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it

```
public Test() {
        long ts = new Date().getTime() + TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney").getOffset(new Date().getTime());
        testtimestamp = new Date(ts);
}

public Test(Integer testid) {
        this();
        this.testid = testid;
}
```